# RecyclerView items misaligned only on add

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that contains items entered in a dialog, the RV is also part of the dialog and the items appear as a button is pressed.  The item is simply a LinearLayout TextView whose width matches the parent RV, and the text of the textview is centered.

The issue is that when I add a new item, they appear to be very far to the left.  It is only when I scroll the item out of view and then bring it back to the items appear in the center.  Also if I close the dialog and reopen it, the items then appear all in the correct alignment on reopening it.  Still, if I add a new item, it will have the wrong alignment.

UPDATE: I changed the background color bc i realized the textview was just too small.  I want the width to match the width of the RV, the text is properly centering but the TV is not filling the width of the RV...  Here's a pic:
[image]

See code below:

**SpecAdapter.kt**

```
    class SpecsAdapter(val context: Context, val specs: List<Specification>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<SpecsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_spec, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = specs.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val spec = specs[position]
        holder.bind(spec)
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(spec: Specification) {
            itemView.tvSpec.text = "    ${spec.name}    "
            if (!spec.include) {
                itemView.tvSpec.apply {
                    paintFlags = Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Activity.kt** (the part with the dialog where the RV appears)

```
fun showSpecificationDialog(specType: String) {
    val searchFormView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.specification_add, null)

    val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Include/Exclude")
        .setView(searchFormView)
        .setNeutralButton("Close", null)
        .show()

    dialog.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etSearch)?.hint = "Enter $specType"

    val rvSpecs = dialog.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rvSpecs)
    val adapter = if (specType == "Ingredient") SpecsAdapter(this, ingredients) else SpecsAdapter(this, tags)
    rvSpecs?.adapter = adapter
    rvSpecs?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    //clicking this adds the item to one of two lists, which appears in the recyclerview
    dialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnInclude)?.setOnClickListener {
        val spec = dialog.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etSearch)?.text.toString()
        if (specType == "Ingredient") {
            ingredients.add(Specification(spec, false, true))
            adapter.notifyItemInserted(ingredients.size - 1)
            Log.i(TAG, "added $spec to ingredients - exclude")
        } else {
            tags.add(Specification(spec, false, true))
            adapter.notifyItemInserted(tags.size - 1)
            Log.i(TAG, "added $spec to tags - exclude")
        }
        dialog.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etSearch)?.setText("")
    }

    //clicking this adds the item to one of two lists, which appears in the recyclerview
    dialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnExclude)?.setOnClickListener {
        val spec = dialog.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etSearch)?.text.toString()
        if (specType == "Ingredient") {
            ingredients.add(Specification(spec, false, false))
            adapter.notifyItemInserted(ingredients.size - 1)
            Log.i(TAG, "added $spec to ingredients - include")
        } else {
            tags.add(Specification(spec, false, false))
            adapter.notifyItemInserted(tags.size - 1)
            Log.i(TAG, "added $spec to tags - include")
        }
        dialog.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etSearch)?.setText("")
    }

    dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL).setOnClickListener {
        dialog.dismiss()
    }
}
```

**specification_add.xml** (this holds the recyclerview and the buttons and whatnot)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etSearch"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Ingredient/Tag" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnExclude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Exclude"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/etSearch"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etSearch" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnInclude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Include"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/etSearch"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etSearch" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvSpecs"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnInclude"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**item_add.xml** (xml file for each individual item in RV)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSpec"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        tools:text="Ingredient/Tag" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show an example of what you're talking about

Comment: so how do you want the items to be formatted

Comment: I want it centered in the RV, but for some reason when it try to center it, the text appears to the far left.  It is as if they textview was centered on the left edge of the RV, bc the text does a linefeed way before it seems to run out of space

Comment: I updated this question with a screenshot of the issue!  I still need help.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not share your code, i think you have to specify match parent instead of wrap content for RecyclerView .